# How to display WMS with zoom level?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, zoom

I'm trying to communicate WMS server of ESRI. I following link below.

```
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.3.0&service=wms&request=GetMap&CRS=4326&bbox=19.416377,-125.192865,54.318281,-66.105824&width=750&height=360&layers=0&styles=default&format=image/png"
```

But it gives me only one zooom level image. I want to use my web map service all zoom layers.

Is it possible to make ? I think i should write some code in the link but i can't find anything for this problem.

Comment: You change the extents in the BBOX parameter. Perhaps you should read up on the basics of WMS also.

Comment: If you read you can lightened me. :) I've read. But dont see anything about it.

Comment: BBOX parameter changes geographic extent. Width/height changes  number of pixels. Changing the first will effectively change the zoom level, while keeping the image the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change bbox from numbers to parametric definition. like %f,%f,%f,%f it will solve your issue.